# how to create array string

Tags: iphone, arrays, string, nsmutablearray

i'm having NSMutableArray which containing student info, now i just want to extract student name and their average mark only, so what i did

```
    NSMutableArray *stuCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[students count]];

for (int i = 0; i < [students count]; i++) 
{
    if([students objectAtIndex:i] != NULL)
    {

    NSDictionary *dic = [students objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *temp = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];

    [stuCollection  addObject:name];

    }   
}


for(int j=0; j< [stuCollection count]; j++)
{
    NSLOG(@"Name %@",[stuCollection objectAtIndex:j]);
}
```

i'm able to run this for first time, but when i make auto scan, i can exe for 1st, 2nd, 3rd loop but then apps terminate show as below,

2009-12-02 14:57:37.908 AppBuzz[13073:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil'
2009-12-02 14:57:37.916 AppBuzz[13073:207] Stack: (
    820145437,
    837578260,
    819694387,
    819694291,
    814683071,
    814716415,
    814716245,
    17529,
    24097,
    814480795,
    819893443,
    819891231,
    858682228,
    861592624,
    861585968,
    8997,
    8860
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

how this can be improve

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand assertions?

```
assert(students);
assert([students count]);

NSMutableArray * stuCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[students count]];
assert(stuCollection);

for (int i = 0; i < [students count]; i++) {
    if ([students objectAtIndex:i] != NULL) {

        NSDictionary * dic = [students objectAtIndex:i];
        assert(dic);

        NSString * temp = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        assert(temp);

        assert(name);

        [stuCollection addObject:name];
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like students is a Cocoa collection, you can use the following:

`NSArray *studentNames = [students valueForKey:@"name"];`

See the KVC [Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/20002176) for more info.